# How old is Queen Amidala meant to be in the Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

This is a question which resulted from the chat area. Some speculated she is supposed to be 14, it is definitely mentioned she is one of the youngest queens ever elected.

How old is she?

Comment: 14 according to [Weird Al Yankovic](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/The-Saga-Begins-lyrics-Weird-Al-Yankovic/4B888A4D49884D724825690E00209E21).

Comment: And how does one get elected queen, anyway?

Comment: I didn't vote for her.

Comment: @Jack - I voted for Cthulu

Comment: In RL we had systems of government in which the ruler was elected, but the voting population was comprised only of nobles and the candidates had to be nobles themselves.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[According to Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala), she was born in [46 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/46_BBY) ([BBY = Before the Battle of Yavin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar)) and became queen in [33 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/33_BBY), so that would make her about 13 when first elected. The Trade Federation invasion occurred in [32 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/32_BBY), so that would make her about 14 at the time of [The Phantom Menace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_Menace).

Comment: FWIW if I remember from the book correctly she was to have been 14 and Anakin was supposed to be 9.

Comment: @Xantec, that's confirmed by Weird Al's "[The Saga Begins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_Begins)," a.k.a. "everything you need to know about _The Phantom Menace_ in 5 minutes and 27 seconds".

Comment: I remember there was information that Amidala is 13 when TPM was out. Can't remember where I read it. (I'm **not** trying to say that she wasn't 14 in the movie.)